# Parsing String - Extract Numeric Characters At End

Tags: r, string, parsing

Parsing string fields in R data frames is a bit of a mystery to me I'm afraid...would be grateful for help.

I have a string field which always ends in an indeterminate number of numeric characters. I'd like to write a bit of code to just extract the numeric part at the end of each.

An example of the data format is:

```
df_test <- data.frame(my_string = c("XXX-0387", "XXXX-1-999999", "XXX 12345432", "XXX-2345", "XXX1234"))
```

What I'd like is to put the numeric part at the end into a new field but to keep any leading zeros - so presumably the new field would have to be chr rather than int. So my output would look like:

```
c("0387", "999999", "12345432", "2345", "1234)
```

Is there an easy way to do this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way using `sub` to capture the last part of string which is number.

```
sub('.*?(\\d+)$', '\\1', df_test$my_string)
#[1] "0387"     "999999"   "12345432" "2345"     "1234"
```

Using `stringr` :

```
stringr::str_extract(df_test$my_string, '\\d+$')
```

Comment: Thank you. Both seem to work. Will probably go with the stringr version - I tend to like all things Tidyverse

Comment: I'm having ahard time understanding `.*?` how can something match at least 0 times (`*`) and at most one time (`?`). I can see from testing it was necessary, I'm just confused. Personally, I can understand something like this more easily `sub('.*\\D(\\d+)$', '\\1', df_test$my_string)`

Comment: @DanielO regex by default are greedy. `.*?` is used to match as less characters as possible before matching a digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexpr` with `\\d+$` to find the numbers at the end and extracti it with `regmatches`.

```
regmatches(df_test$my_string, regexpr("\\d+$", df_test$my_string))
#[1] "0387"     "999999"   "12345432" "2345"     "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stri_extract_last` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last(df_test$my_string, regex = "\\d+")
#[1] "0387"     "999999"   "12345432" "2345"     "1234"
```